# configuration error directories not present

Tags: configuration

I am brand new to trying to create a web blog so I am hoping you can help me get started. I haven't been able to find answer online.

My status report has this error.

Configuration directories   Not present
Your sites/recoverypractices.dd/settings.php file must define the $config_directories variable as an array containing the names of directories in which configuration files can be found. It must contain a sync key.

I don't know what thes sync key is but I did find a sync folder here D:\Sites\devdesktop\drupal-8.2.5\core\modules\field\tests\modules\field_test_config
I found the following code in my settings.php file but I don't know exactly how to fill in the array or define the sync key.

- @code
- $config_directories = array(
- CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY => '/directory/outside/webroot',
- );
- @endcode
  */

Can you assist me in figuring out how to fix this error?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1):

You can define it in settings.php like so:

```
$config_directories[CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY] = '/../config/sync';
```

This sets the default sync directory outside my webroot.

`CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY` is a constant defined for 'sync'.

Comment: This works. The problem is a known issue in Acquia Dev Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Just replacing up this code instead of $config_directories in settings.php file fixed the issue.

$config_directories = array(
  CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY => 'sites/default/files/config_acqTmp-2017-02-06T19.38.23-2536',
  );

I am not sure how much secure this is but now in my status report tab the Configuration files shows **Protected**

Comment: This is more or less the answer I gave earlier.